# How to parametrise a two value string in powershell("user:mary@contoso.com:rwx,default:user:mary@contoso.com:rwx")

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am new on Powershell
I parameterise the below variables in Powershell.

```
$accountName = "abc" 
$container = "test" 
$rootDir = "Folder1"
$absoluteAcl = "user:mary@contoso.com:rwx,default:user:mary@contoso.com:rwx"

So i used the below code to parameterise above variable.
param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "")]
   [string]$accountName1 = $accountName,

   [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "")]
   [string]$container1 = $container,

   [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "")]
   [string]$rootDir1 = $rootDir,

   [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "")]
   [string]$userinput1 = $absoluteAcl,
```

When i input the value of $userinput1 = user:mary@contoso.com:rwx,default:user:mary@contoso.com:rwx

My script break due to string value
How I can pass this string = user:mary@contoso.com:rwx,default:user:mary@contoso.com:rwx as a parameterise value.

I have tried below option
"user:mary@contoso.com:rwx,default:user:mary@contoso.com:rwx"
"user:mary@contoso.com:rwx","default:user:mary@contoso.com:rwx"

None of them is working.

Comment: You have asked the [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62990960/9898643) yesterday, and it was closed because it lacks details. What you apparently want to send as parameter is an [AclEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.datalake.store.acl.aclentry?view=azure-dotnet) object, but instead you are sending its string representation. That _could_ be fine if the rest of your script turns this back into a new AclEntry object using the `ParseAclEntryString() method.

Comment: However, as it is now, nobody can be sure because again you do not show how the script uses this input and also you do not show us the **complete** exception message you are receiving. _None of them is working_ is not very helpfull..

Answer (score 0):

Pass them as a string array:

```
$accountName = "abc" 
$container = "test" 
$rootDir = "Folder1"   
$absoluteAcl = "user:mary@contoso.com:rwx","default:user:mary@contoso.com:rwx"

# So i used the below code to parameterise above variable.
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "")]
   [string]$accountName1 = $accountName,

   [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "")]
   [string]$container1 = $container,

   [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "")]
   [string]$rootDir1 = $rootDir,

   [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "")]
   [string[]]$userinput1 = $absoluteAcl,
```

`string[]` means to accept an comma separated array of strings. I have also changed $absoluteAcl to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for valuable comments, I have changed the script as you suggested. The provided solution didn't work fo script. Below script userinput1[0] : "user:mary@contoso.com:rwx","default:user:mary@contoso.com:rwx"  Then again it ask for value userinput1[1] :                       i leave it blank

Comment: Thanks. If it works, please upvote it and accept it by clicking the big ^ and tick button.